# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'). Terminal hit this error after deployment of script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get such a problem in my code. I fight and fight, I still haven't found an error :(

Terminal after call this script hit " TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

````
  const nft = "cardienft.json";

  
  let rares = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(nft));
  let nonce = 73;
  for(let i = 0; i < 2000; i += 25) {
      let moonies = [];
      for(let j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
        moonies.push({ uri: rares.doggies[i+j].uri, moonieType: 6 });
      }
      console.log(await Gateway.forgeRares(moonies, { gasLimit: 10000000, gasPrice: 2000000000, nonce: nonce }));
      nonce++;
      console.log(i + ' to ' + (i+25) + ' forged');
  } ```
````

Comment: At what line do you get this exception? line 2? Can you add more `console.log`? I don't see `const fs = require('fs');` line, do you have that?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at main (/Users/mikolajrucinski/Desktop/hardhat-hackathon-boilerplate-3/scripts/deploy.js:26:42)
  a console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your code arrives at this line :

```
moonies.push({ uri: rares.doggies[i+j].uri, moonieType: 6 });
```

`rares` is an empty object , so `rares.doggies` is undefined

`i` and `j` are `0` and `i+j = 0`
it want to read `0` key from `undefined(rares.doggies)`.

you can log `rares` before starting for loop to get sure and then handle its value

or you can add a `?` between `rares.doggies` and `[i+j]` like this:

```
moonies.push({ uri: rares.doggies?.[i+j].uri, moonieType: 6 });
```

as a trick

Comment: got a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'" just copy paste yours line :(

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the question mark and the dot, and now I've editted it. Please try the edited code @EccoMoon

Comment: now gotta "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

Comment: so your previous reported problem has been solved. and now there is another problem in another line. .can you please check the error line in your console error

Comment: when I fire up console.log (moonies) it gets an array with undefined "uri". Looks like I can't read "uri" from a json.

Comment: `moonies` is your new array and it will have any value that you have pushed to it
so if `moonies` has undefined uri's, you should check why rares.doggies[i+j].uri is undefined, maybe rares has not correct values or maybe uri is really undefined in this index of it, you should put an await before fs.readFileSyncJSON in some versions of node. like this : parse(await fs.readFileSync(nft));

Comment: if you have any type errors you can put another ?. where ever error is

Comment: or you can specify a default value if you don't want to fill with undefined like this: moonies.push({ uri: rares.doggies?.[i+j]?.uri ?? '', moonieType: 6 });